# Can't run the program imported from Github in eclipse.-

Tags: java, eclipse, github, materialfx

[image][image]
The option for list out the files inside it in PROJECT EXPLORER, doesnot work
The code is displayed in white and doesn't run.
The github link is :
https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX.git

I have imported it as required ! Can somebody tell me why the Demo.java program doesn't run. I had imported another project from git, which runs flawlessly. Help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The screenshots show the Git perspective. Please switch to the Java perspective (via the icon in the upper right) and show the project structure in the _Package Explorer_ view to make sure there are no errors (and if there are errors, add the error messages as text to your question).

Comment: What does "doesn't run" mean?

Comment: @howlger , i cant check what files are inside it because the option to list out the project structure , isnt there. I have posted it in the first picture..

Comment: @nitind , there is no option to run the program. when i click on Run as.. instead of showing java application, it is empty.

Comment: `MaterialFX` is a Gradle project, but according to your screenshot it has not been imported as a Gradle project. Delete the project without its content and all created files (see _Git Staging_ view) and then import it via _File > Import...: Gradle > Existing Gradle Project_.