# Project doesnt get build in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, javafx, materialfx

I have been trying to run MaterialFx demo project for a while but have been unsuccessful. I posted the tile:Project doesnt get build in Eclipse.. Is this project not being built ?  I dont know if the project hasnot been built or compiled, I had posted about this earlier as well. LINK: [Can't run the program imported from Github in eclipse.-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73401907/cant-run-the-program-imported-from-github-in-eclipse)

.. I dont know what problem it is. The code is white.. and when i try to run it.. The option to run it as a java program also doesnt show up.. According to the comment in earlier post, I have imported it as a Gradle project too. Can someboy guide me why the program doesnt run like other programs. Help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Check your Problems View for problems.

Comment: I don't know if there's more issues regarding Eclipse, but I was able to get the demo working by switching from Java 18 to Java 17. Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @Slaw, i am using java 17 bruh

Comment: To get it working I cloned the repo (`git clone <repo>`), then navigated to the cloned project's directory (`cd MaterialFX`), and then executed Gradle (`.\gradlew :demo:run`), where Gradle was executing on Java 17. Does that work for you? I know that doesn't involve Eclipse, but it would be good to know if you can get it working outside any IDE.

Comment: @Slaw, I did as you instructed.. This error came up. > Task :demo:compileJava FAILED
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':demo:compileJava'.
> Unsupported class file major version 62

Comment: "_Unsupported class file major version 62_" -- That means you're using Java 18, not 17. Make sure Gradle is using Java 17 and try again.

Comment: The source of the problem is that the version of the Gradle wrapper is not recent enough to support Java 18, causing some problems with ASM. So, the other option is to update the wrapper to use Gradle 7.5.1. The owner of the repository says [Gradle will be updated in an upcoming release](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX/issues/240#issuecomment-1228774483).